# Countably Infinite Sets and Equivalence Relations

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have a countably infinite set $X$, that is $|X|=|\mathbb{N}|$. Is it true that $|X|=|\mathbb{N}|$ implies that $|X|\sim |\mathbb{N}|$. If so, does this mean that
$$|X|\sim |\mathbb{N}|\iff |\mathbb{N}|\sim|X|, $$
by the symmetric property of equivalence of sets?

I am not sure how the cardinality of countably infinite sets relation to equivalence relations.

Comment: im not sure of your question, i believe all three statements have the same meaning

Comment: Oh. I thought that $|X|\sim |\mathbb{N}|$ iff $X$ was finite. It is also true if $X$ is infinite?

Comment: it is true for an X which has countably infinite elements as well

Comment: @Steven , am curious why you thought $|X|=|\mathbb{N}|$ iff $X$ was finite. Did you read that somewhere, have a reference for it maybe?

Comment: @auspicious99 I thought that $|X|=|\mathbb{N}|\implies X\sim\mathbb{N}$ iff $X$ was finite. This is my first exposure to set theory, and I was unsure of the relation between cardinality and equivalence (if you have any resources, i'd like to read them).

Comment: @Steven The wikipedia article on cardinality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) could be a reasonable starting point. Perhaps it may clarify regarding the multiple meanings of the $|X|$ notation too, in case that may have been a source of confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Cardinality places an equivalence relation on sets. So, $|X|=|\mathbb{N}|$ implies that $|X|\sim |\mathbb{N}|$ by the definition of this equivalence relation.

So, yes, also we can write
$$|X|\sim |\mathbb{N}|\iff |\mathbb{N}|\sim|X|, $$
by the symmetric property of equivalence of sets.